# How I suppress a TS2322 warning in WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, react-native, webstorm, eslint

I have a project in WebStorm created using `expo init` with the IDE configured to use ESLint with `@typescript-eslint` and with "Typescript Language Service" enabled (and TSLint disabled).

If I replace the contents of `App.tsx` [with](http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/component_api) the code below, I get numerous inspection errors highlighted in the IDE's editor. I can (as expected) eliminate most of these with

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility, @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define, @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type */
```

but some errors persist, notably

[image]

associated with each `Component` in `App`'s `render`. As expected I can also disable these errors by disabling "Typescript Language Service", but not (despite the IDE suggesting it) with `@ts-ignore` (in any scope).

The only thing that works cleanly is to replace

```
class Counter extends Component
```

with

```
class Counter extends Component<any>
```

What is the correct approach to suppressing the `TS2322` error in my project? Why does using `<any>` work (and should I use it) and why does `@ts-ignore` have no effect?

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

class Counter extends Component {

  state = {count: 0}

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    const {count} = this.state
    const {color, size} = this.props

    return (
      <Text style={{color, fontSize: size}}>
        {count}
      </Text>
    )
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Counter color={'lightblue'} size={16} />
        <Counter color={'skyblue'} size={32} />
        <Counter color={'steelblue'} size={80} />
        <Counter color={'darkblue'} size={140} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
})
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can put `@ts-ignore` right above the component in JSX to get it suppressed, like:

```
  {/* 
  // @ts-ignore */}
  <Counter color={'lightblue'} size={16} />
```

(see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27552.)

But I'd strongly recommend re-writing your components in [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#react-integration) way to get rid of compiler errors, like:

```
interface IProps {
    color: string;
    size: number;
}

interface IState {
    count: number;
};

export default class Counter extends Component<IProps, IState> {...}
```

Comment: Excellent! Although the first solution wasn't working (`// @ts-ignore` gets rendered or generates fatal errors on rendering), the second works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The most painless solution I could find is this:

```
    let foo: string = 'foohoho';
    let bar: number = 42;
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore
    foo = bar;
```

For the record: I am using this in my `spec.ts` tests file when I want to test a crashing case. Please do not twist TypeScript's hands.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use `@ts-expect-error` instead of `@ts-ignore`. It works the same way, except that `@ts-ignore` won't error if it doesn't find an error.

```
// @ts-expect-error
<MyComponent value={myValue} />

<MyComponent
    value1={value1}
    value2={value2}
    // @ts-expect-error
    valueWithError={valueWithError}
/>
```

> Sometimes, you'll want to ignore an error that later down the line
> gets fixed. If you're using @ts-ignore, it'll just ignore the fact
> that the error is gone.
>
> But with @ts-expect-error, you'll actually get a hint that the
> directive is now safe to remove. So if you're choosing between them,
> pick @ts-expect-error.

(from: https://www.totaltypescript.com/concepts/how-to-use-ts-expect-error)